# How to use category filter using arraytodatatable in google chart

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, google-visualization, pygooglechart

Is there any way to use category filter in arraytodatatable  type of google chart

Comment: Ask google ;-) Seems no code issue here. No real question (where is the`?`). SO helps on code issue not on `want to now` stuff.

Comment: [`arrayToDataTable`](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#google.visualization.arraytodatatae) is just a static helper method that returns a [`DataTable`](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataTable)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/datatables_dataviews) can help you but for this kind of questions I think that's better google.